# $\ker(A)^\perp=\operatorname{Im}(A)$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and $A:H \longrightarrow H$ a symmetric operator, that is, $(Au,v)_H=(u,Av)_H$ for all $u,v \in H$. Then, $\ker(A)^\perp=\operatorname{Im}(A)$.

My attempt:

$``\ker(A)^\perp \supset\operatorname{Im}(A)"$

Let $v \in \operatorname{Im}(A)$, then $v=Au$ for some $u \in H$. Thus,
\begin{eqnarray}
(v,w)_{H}&=&(Au,w)\\
&=&(u,Aw)\\
&=&0,
\end{eqnarray}
for all $w \in \ker(A)$. Therefore, $v \in \ker(A)^\perp$.

Unfortunately, I could not prove the other inclusion.

Comment: The other inclusion is wrong. In fact, $\ker(A)^\perp = \overline{\operatorname{Im}(A)}$. For the proof, you should better prove that $\ker A = (\operatorname{Im}A)^\perp$ and then take orthogonal complements.

Comment: Could you show me how to prove it?

Comment: And if I add the hypothesis that $A$ is continuous, would that help prove what I want?

Comment: As a symmetric operator defined on the whole space, $A$ is automatically continuous. And I won't show the proof to you because it's mainly what you already did. You can edit your answer and I will have a look. That's what I can offer you.

Comment: For finite dim. spaces its just a dimension argument that completes the proof.